# How to get Select2 value from asp.net code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I have Dropdownlist that has only one element:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="select2" ID="ddl" runat="server" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", "value"));
    }
}
```

Also my `ddl` gets data from ajax call. 
When I'm trying to get changed value from code behind it still returns value of first element.

```
 string value = ddl.SelectedValue; //I got data from ajax call, changed value but it still returns first "value"
```

But from javascript I can get changed value, so now on every change in my ddl I copy value to hidden field so I can get value from codebehind

```
$("#ddl").change(function () {
   $('#hidden_for_ddl').val($("#ddl").val());
});
```

Finally I can get selected value from code, is it easier way to solve my problem?

```
string value = hidden_for_ddl.Value; //returns "selected value"
```

Comment: When you use `select2` and you change the value of the `select` the original `select`'s value changes to so you suppose to get the right value from the `#ddl` itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
string value = Empty.String;
foreach (ListItem item in ddl) {
    if ((item.Selected == true)) {
value = item.Value;
return;
    }
}
```

This will go through each item and set the string value when it finds one that is selected.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, i can't improve the answer.